# Как посчитать количество итераций при проверке элемента

Tags: java, http, soap

Всем привет. Есть вебсервис отдающий и получающий определенные теги. Нужно сделать так, что бы он при 3 итерации одного и того же элемента отдавал уже другой тег. 
Реализовал так, только как сделать что бы с 3 итерациией этого же элемента выводился другой тег?

```
public class EmulBPA implements SkeletonInterface {
    Integer i = null;

    public BPAGetResponseDocument BPAGet(bpa10.BPAGetDocument BPAGet4) throws MsgWSTechnicalException, MsgWSAppTechnicalException, MsgWSAppException, MsgWSAccessException, MsgWSVerificationException {

        BPAGetResponseDocument Ret = BPAGetResponseDocument.Factory.newInstance();
        BPAGetResponse response = Ret.addNewWSAccountMoneyTransferBPAGetResponse();
        BPAGetResponseType out = response.addNewResponse();
        BPAGetOutParms outParms = out.addNewOutParms();
        WSCommonOutParms commonParms = out.addNewOutCommonParms();
        WSExtention commonParmsExt = commonParms.addNewOutCommonParmsExt();
        commonParmsExt.setName("UID");
        String ref = (BPAGet4.getBPAGet().getInParms().getRef()).replaceAll("\\D", ""); 

        if ( ref != null && !ref.equals(""))
        {
            i = Integer.parseInt(ref);
        }

        if(i == null) {
           outParms.setWts("NOT");
           outParms.setWtsc("FND");
        } else if(i == i) {
            outParms.setWts("WRA");
            outParms.setWtsc("");        
        } 
        else
        {
            outParms.setWts("WRC");
            outParms.setWtsc("");              
        }  

        return Ret;
    }
```

Comment: Над простым счётчиком итераций не думал?

Comment: А можно код, который бы можно было запустить и понять о чем речь?

Comment: `if (i == i)` может `if (i == 3)` ?

Comment: в тег ref приходит стринг аля несколько букв и число н-значное. В моем варианте идет проверка на приход пустого тега (null) и если тег совпадает с ним же то выводится WRA. Вот вывод иного значения для тега при повторной итерации и не получается придумать.

Comment: Если задать i == 3, то тег вернется, если значение ref будет 3. Тут же нужно возвращать WRA, когда всего 2 итерации с данным значением, и WRC, когда больше 3.